# Have I done a sufficient job of sealing my window?

Tags: windows, leak, sealing

Water seems to be leaking from under our window frame.  I assume it's from the window tracks. I'm not sure if this is a problem that needs to be addressed or not. I resealed the exterior of the frame as you can probably see on the top and sides, but left the bottom open.

Is there anywhere else I should seal or is the water coming from the bottom of the frame normal?

We don't have any interior leaking.

[image: Window "leaking" at bottom]

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting that the wind is overcoming the drip edge shape to push some water back against the house.

For my windows, you can remove the movable panel and remove the bottom track to clean under it. I can see the weep holes when it's all disassembled (I usually sneak the short part of a little Alan wrench under the track and pull on the long part with pliers to get the track free). I have a weep hole at each end, where your water evidence at the middle doesn't match my expectations for water coming out of the weep holes. I would instead expect lots of water at each end. You could experiment by pouring lots of water into the track.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking and hoping it was the wind doing that